# Saving a Date using adelevie/parse-ruby-client gives error Parse::ParseProtocolError 111: invalid type for key *, expected date, but got string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

I have initialized my parse-ruby-client with my Parse API key and Client ID.

Here is the code for saving a date:

```
dbObject = MyParse.object("ClassName")
dbObject["startTime"] = Date.new
result = dbObject.save
```

However I get the following error on the second line:

`Parse::ParseProtocolError in EventsController#create<br>
111: invalid type for key startTime, expected date, but got string`

Comment: When I change the second line to `dbObject["startTime"] = []`, the error changes to `111: invalid type for key startTime, expected date, but got array`. I believe `Date.new` is being recognized as a string, but I do not know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to save the start time of my event to Parse by writing and calling a cloud code function instead of saving the value directly from the .rb file.

events_controller.rb:

```
params = {"name" => @event.name,
          "startTime" => @event.startTime}
function = Parse::Cloud::Function.new("createEvent") 
function.call(params)
```

cloud_code.js:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createEvent", function(req, res) {

  var name = req.params.name;
  var startTime = new Date(req.params.startTime);

  var parseClass = Parse.Object.extend("ClassName");
  var event = new parseClass();

  event.set('name', name);
  event.set('startTime', startTime);

  event.save(null, {
    success: function(event) { 
      res.success('Successfully ran createEvent');
    },
    error: function(event, error) {
      res.error(error);
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error prompt you: for `dbObject["startTime"]`, the key("startTime") should be a date type, but "startTime" is a string type.

You should change `dbObject["startTime"]` to `dbObject[Date.new]`(or other data type value) depend on your needs.